# Smooth scroll div id to div id not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi im building a website, now i am trying to make when u click on a div u smooth scroll to the other div but it is not working here is the code i am using:

```
<script>
$("#knop").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#nieuws").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

The two divs:

```
<div class="nieuwsbrief" id="knop" style="text-align:center; cursor: pointer;">BLIJF OP DE HOOGTE<br> MET ONZE NIEUWSBRIEF</div>

<div id="nieuws"></div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: remove the `,` from your second selector.

Comment: @KevinKloet still doesnt work :(

Comment: @prasad Why is CSS needed?, there is no css on those div's

Comment: [seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/kevin_kloet/tmsgbh6v/)

Comment: There is not enough content on your page to be scroll able.

Comment: Question is missing context and info but you probably bind event on element not available in DOM. Try at least to wrap it in ready handler

Comment: Work fine for me see: https://jsfiddle.net/ojedafa1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to vertically scrolling backwards and forwards between two divs, using plain vanilla javascript:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

var verticalGapInPixels = 624;
var scrollIncrementInPixels = 2;
var numberOfIntervals = (verticalGapInPixels / scrollIncrementInPixels);

function scrollBetweenDivs() {
 var i = 0;
 var scrollIncrement = (this.id === 'div1' ? scrollIncrementInPixels : -scrollIncrementInPixels);

    var scrollByInterval = setInterval(
     function(){
      window.scrollBy(0,scrollIncrement);
      i++;
      if (i >= numberOfIntervals) {clearInterval(scrollByInterval);}
     },1
    );
}

div1.addEventListener('click',scrollBetweenDivs,false);
div2.addEventListener('click',scrollBetweenDivs,false);
```

```css
div {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin: 12px auto 500px;
text-align: center;
border: 2px solid rgb(63,63,63);
cursor: pointer;
}

div p {
font-size: 12px;
}

#div1 {
background: rgb(191,191,191);
}

#div2 {
background: rgb(127,127,127);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<h2>Div 1</h2>
<p>Click to Scroll<br />Down to Div 2</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<h2>Div 2</h2>
<p>Click to Scroll<br />Up to Div 1</p>
</div>
```